# Host grub error after installing Virtualbox - Non Recoverable

Tags: 12.04, virtualbox, grubrescue

I have been unable to fine a resolution to my problem and I have been suffering from it for a while.

I can install Virtualbox and can reboot the machine successfully straight after. Once the system is back up I can run Virtualbox ans start working towards creating a new machine.

So, say I am installing an XP machine. 1 time out of 10 it will work successfully first time. If it doesn't work (i.e BSOD), I delete the machine and start again.

But when the time comes to finish up and switch off my computer, but it doesn't happen gracefully. As soon as I click shutdown, The machine dies.

When the machine is switched back on I get:

> Error: no such device
>
> grub resuce>

I boot up my Grub Fix Live CD, but the grub reinstaller get stuck on searching for partitions, gparted just get stuck looking for devices and even `fdisk -l` drops a line and displays nothing and is the same. Stuck.

The only way I know how to sort it is by re-installing Ubuntu.

Has anyone had this problem, or know how to fix it?

**/etc/fstab**

```
#/etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
proc            /proc           proc    nodev,noexec,nosuid 0       0
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=117df936-b581-4f8d-9c95-84ad0a9d6eb7 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro
0  1
# swap was on /dev/sda6 during installation
UUID=7ff0d94e-dd35-450b-8ed4-6a126d76cca6 none            swap    sw    0   0
/dev/fd0        /media/floppy0  auto    rw,user,noauto,exec,utf8 0       0
```

**/boot/grub/grub.cfg**

```
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
set default="0"
if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi
function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
   saved_entry="${chosen}"
   save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
 set recordfail=1
 if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  insmod vbe
  insmod vga
  insmod video_bochs
  insmod video_cirrus
}
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 117df936-b581-4f8d-9c95-84ad0a9d6eb7
if loadfont /usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2 ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  insmod part_msdos
  insmod ext2
  set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 117df936-b581-4f8d-9c95-84ad0a9d6eb7
  set locale_dir=($root)/boot/grub/locale
  set lang=en_GB
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ]; then
  set timeout=-1
else
  set timeout=2
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 117df936-b581-4f8d-9c95-84ad0a9d6eb7
insmod png
if background_image /usr/share/images/desktop-base/spacefun-grub.png; then
  set color_normal=light-gray/black
  set color_highlight=white/black
else
  set menu_color_normal=white/black
  set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
  if background_color 44,0,30; then
   clear
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
set gfxpayload="${1}"if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
else
set vt_handoff=
fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
   if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
 if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
 set linux_gfx_mode=keep
 else
set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
else
set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
 else
   set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
if [ "${linux_gfx_mode}" != "text" ]; then load_video; fi
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-34-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
recordfail
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 117df936-b581-4f8d-9c95-84ad0a9d6eb7
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-34-generic root=UUID=117df936-b581-4f8d-9c95-84ad0a9d6eb7 ro
initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-34-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-34-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
recordfail
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 117df936-b581-4f8d-9c95-84ad0a9d6eb7
echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-34-generic ...'
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-34-generic root=UUID=117df936-b581-4f8d-
95-84ad0a9d6eb7 ro recovery nomodeset 
echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-34-generic
}
submenu "Previous Linux versions" {
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-23-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux
-class gnu --class os {
recordfail
gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 117df936-b581-4f8d-9c95-84ad0a9d6eb7
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=UUID=117df936-b581-4f8d-
95-84ad0a9d6eb7 ro   
initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-23-generic
}
menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 3.5.0-23-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu 
--class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os {
recordfail
insmod gzio
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 117df936-b581-4f8d-9c95-84ad0a9d6eb7
echo    'Loading Linux 3.5.0-23-generic ...'
linux   /boot/vmlinuz-3.5.0-23-generic root=UUID=117df936-b581-4f8d-
95-84ad0a9d6eb7 ro recovery nomodeset 
echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...
initrd  /boot/initrd.img-3.5.0-23-generic
}
}
### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+)" {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 117df936-b581-4f8d-9c95-84ad0a9d6eb7
linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin
}
menuentry "Memory test (memtest86+, serial console 115200)" {
insmod part_msdos
insmod ext2
set root='(hd0,msdos5)'
search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 117df936-b581-4f8d-9c95-84ad0a9d6eb7
linux16 /boot/memtest86+.bin console=ttyS0,115200n8
}
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
## BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

**Installation log for Virtualbox**

```
jonathon@BACAGE:~$ sudo apt-get install virtualbox
[sudo] password for jonathon:
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  dkms fakeroot libgsoap1 virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
Suggested packages:
  virtualbox-guest-additions-iso vde2
The following NEW packages will be installed
  dkms fakeroot libgsoap1 virtualbox virtualbox-dkms virtualbox-qt
0 upgraded, 6 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 23.7 MB of archives.
After this operation, 71.4 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Get:1 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/main dkms all 2.2.0.3-1ubuntu3.1 [73.2 kB]
Get:2 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/main fakeroot i386 1.18.2-1 [87.9 kB]
Get:3 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise/universe libgsoap1 i386 2.8.4-2 [518 kB]
Get:4 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe virtualbox i386 4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.3 [15.8 MB]
Get:5 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe virtualbox-dkms all 4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.3 [676 kB]
Get:6 http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ precise-updates/universe virtualbox-qt i386 4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.3 [6,523 kB]
Fetched 23.7 MB in 54s (433 kB/s) 
Selecting previously unselected package dkms.
(Reading database ... 225007 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking dkms (from .../dkms_2.2.0.3-1ubuntu3.1_all.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package fakeroot.
Unpacking fakeroot (from .../fakeroot_1.18.2-1_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package libgsoap1.
Unpacking libgsoap1 (from .../libgsoap1_2.8.4-2_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox.
Unpacking virtualbox (from .../virtualbox_4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.3_i386.deb) ...
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-dkms.
Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (from .../virtualbox-dkms_4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.3_all.deb)
..
Selecting previously unselected package virtualbox-qt.
Unpacking virtualbox-qt (from .../virtualbox-qt_4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.3_i386.deb) ...
Processing triggers for man-db ...
Processing triggers for ureadahead ...
ureadahead will be reprofiled on next reboot
Processing triggers for menu ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info ...
Unknown media type in type 'all/all'
Unknown media type in type 'all/allfiles'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mms'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmst'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/mmsu'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/pnm'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspt'
Unknown media type in type 'uri/rtspu'
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf.index...
Processing triggers for gnome-menus ...
Setting up dkms (2.2.0.3-1ubuntu3.1) ...
Setting up fakeroot (1.18.2-1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/bin/fakeroot-sysv to provide /usr/bin/fakeroot (fakeroot) in auto mode.
Setting up libgsoap1 (2.8.4-2) ...
Setting up virtualbox (4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.3) ...
 * Stopping VirtualBox kernel modules                                            [ OK ] 
 * Starting VirtualBox kernel modules                                   
       * No suitable module for running kernel found                            [fail]
invoke-rc.d: initscript virtualbox, action "restart" failed.
Processing triggers for python-central ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.3) ...
Loading new virtualbox-4.1.12 DKMS files...
First Installation: checking all kernels...
Building only for 3.5.0-34-generic
Building initial module for 3.5.0-34-generic
Done.
vboxdrv:
Running module version sanity check.
Original module
No original module exists within this kernel
Installation
Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/updates/dkms/
vboxnetadp.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
Original module
No original module exists within this kernel
Installation
Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/updates/dkms/
vboxnetflt.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
Original module
No original module exists within this kernel
Installation
Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/updates/dkms/
vboxpci.ko:
Running module version sanity check.
Original module
No original module exists within this kernel
Installation
Installing to /lib/modules/3.5.0-34-generic/updates/dkms/
depmod..........
DKMS: install completed.
Stopping VirtualBox kernel - modules        [ OK ] 
Starting VirtualBox kernel modules          [ OK ]  
Setting up virtualbox-qt (4.1.12-dfsg-2ubuntu0.3) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin ...
ldconfig deferred processing now taking place
Processing triggers for menu ...
jonathon@BACAGE:~$
```

Comment: The only cause I can think of for losing the boot partition repeatedly is if the disk is bad to start with. I've never had VirtualBox corrupt the physical boot block or partition. Can you reboot the Ubuntu system repeatedly before installing VirtualBox? What version of Ubuntu are you using, and what version of VirtualBox?
Please post a copy of the /etc/fstab and /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

Comment: (originally posted as an answer by [TomC](http://askubuntu.com/users/169949/tomc)) Can you reboot the Ubuntu system repeatedly before installing VirtualBox?
What version of Ubuntu are you using, and what version of VirtualBox? Please post a copy of the `/etc/fstab` and `/boot/grub/grub.cfg`.

Comment: Thanks @gertvdijk. Rebooting/Shuting Down works not a problem every time I do it. No matter how many times I do it. I thought this was a weird one also. O/P of my files are posted above

Comment: Please **edit** your question to provide the requested information. Comments are not fit for that.

Comment: Ok, So I tried a Chrome OS build and there was problems with GNOME starting but this is due to my GPU being crap! But it booted a machine and I successfully managed to shutdown and restart. I will try with an XP machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SUCCESS!!!

Finally I have a working XP and stable, bootable Ubuntu.

I ran virtualbox as root!! As simple as that.